How can I correctly resolve environment variables in Playwright tests for a React project built with Vite?
I'm encountering an issue with environment variable access in my tests for a project using Vite as a build tool alongside a React app. In the React app, environment variables are accessed via import.meta.env, but in our tests, we rely on process.env and .env files using the dotenv package.
I'm seeing the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MODE')

Could anyone suggest how to resolve this issue and properly access MODE within both the React app and the test environment?
# src/constants.ts

let BASE_URL: string;

const testMode = import.meta.env.MODE;

if (testMode === "testing") {
  BASE_URL = "http://testing.com";
} else if (testMode === "dev") {
  BASE_URL = "http://dev.com";
} else {
  BASE_URL = "http://production.com";
}

export { BASE_URL };

# playwright.config.ts


import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";
import { BASE_URL as baseURL } from "./src/constants";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ path:  '.env' });

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: "./e2e",
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: "html",
  use: {
    baseURL // using the baseURL that is used by APP as well,
    trace: "on-first-retry",
  },

});

Link to the repo with repro example: https://github.com/omelnik/playwright-vite-repro

Can you share the code in the question? Links go down over time and we want this to be a resource for future visitors with the same problem 5 years from now. Thanks.

Why don't you use dotenv in both React and Playwright sides?

@I.sh. i do use dotenv on both sides

does your .env file exist in root of your project where vite.config exist? have you tried importing your env data using BUN?

cause Bun uses a different approach for importing .env

Why not simply add a fallback in the constant like:
const testMode = import?.meta?.env?.MODE || process?.env?.MODE;

if (testMode === "testing") {
  BASE_URL = "http://testing.com";
}
...


I would consider it a last resort. I would rather avoid altering the app's code to accommodate that.

Imo, since you use import.meta.env in config file playwright.config.ts, it's better to switch to just use process.env altogether since import.meta.env isn't even available in vite.config.js file. In other words, import.meta.env is not meant to be used in config files
